# Intern 3.4 on IOS safari

Tags: ios, appium, ios-simulator, mobile-safari, intern

When I try to execute intern script on ios simulator, safari window launches out side of simulator and opens page let's browse and further script will never execute.
this is happening for all simulators?
This was working previously, but I played little with npm install ios-deploy, tried to install it and remove it.
but since then it stopped working.

And could can anyone please tell me the need of ios-deploy  in case of executing intern script on ios simulator.

I have tried shutdown erase of ios simulator and ios deploy

Sample intern.js file  `define({

```
defaultTimeout: 900000,

reporters: [{id: 'LcovHtml', directory: 'InternHTMLResult'}, {id: 'Console'}],
```

environments: [
        {   platformName: 'iOS',
            deviceName: 'iPhone 6', // for example

bundleId: 'com.apple.mobilesafari', // for example
            automationName: 'XCUITest',
 browserName: 'safari',
            //platformVersion: '10.3', // for example
            Simulator: true,

fixSessionCapabilities: false
      }
    ],
    maxConcurrency: 5,

```
 tunnel: 'NullTunnel',
tunnelOptions : {
    port: Number('4723')
},

functionalSuites: ['tests/functional/3DExpLogin1.js'],
excludeInstrumentation: true
```

//  excludeInstrumentation: /^(?:node_modules)//
});

`

Comment: Could you post your Intern test config somewhere? Also, are you using appium? (That's the typical way to run iOS browser based tests.)

Comment: Yes I am using appium 1.8